# Can you do HTML right to left?

Tags: html, right-to-left

Can you do HTML right to left? For example if you are Arabian could you type html right to left? I would like to know for reasons.

Comment: You can use text direction property `direction` in CSS. Check this [link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/)

Comment: What do you mean by typing html right to left? We type by pressing keys in succession. Do you mean that the tags would visually appear running right to left, somehow? This would depend on the editing software and would be rather off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set direction from right to left by htm then you can right this code in html tag

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
```

Or

with css you can add the property to element i.e div as given below

```
div
{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. 
The code is code. It's interpreted by your browser, and displayed on your screen just so. The browser (well most browsers) interpret the HTML the same way, and that's from **Top to Bottom** and then from right to left.

So concerning HTML syntax, and in which direction you code in, left to right, would be the most universally accepted way.

Unfortunately, English is seen as the Universal language, for HTML and programming also.

From a maintenance perspective: It's also better for all code to share the same language, so that all coders from any race or country can understand it.

Comment: Wondering if there is such a thing as a RTL editor that flips HTML when saving... You never know!

Comment: You want to write like this? - `<""=elyts vid>` :p